# Angular App deploy to Azure website message “You do not have permission to view this directory or page.”

Tags: angular, azure

Deploying an Angular 8 web app to Azure website using an Azure DevOps pipeline shows the following message when trying to load the web app in the browser.

“You do not have permission to view this directory or page.”

[image]

I spent many hours trying to figure out what might be missing. I tried adding web.config file, updated the Path mapping but nothing really worked.

Answer (score 0):

I spent many hours trying to fix this same issue when I deployed my Angular 8 application to Azure Web App. After trying many things, I fixed this issue by specifying the default document in Azure Web App Configuration settings. It worked. I found out about this by enabling the 'App Service Logs' to get Application Logs (Detailed Error Messages, Application Logging). This showed the log error shown below.

"HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory."
"A default document is not configured for the requested URL, and directory browsing is not enabled on the server."

I don't know why Azure Web App was suddenly not recognising the 'index.html' file in the site/wwwroot folder. However adding 'index.html' in the 'Default Documents' section fixed it.

[image]

[image]